# Laravel Policies: Is there a bug? a cache? how to solve?

Tags: php, laravel

I see the very same problem here: [Laravel policies : code change is ignored. Is there any policy cache to clear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58398835/laravel-policies-code-change-is-ignored-is-there-any-policy-cache-to-clear) and here: [Laravel Policy bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57824918/laravel-policy-bug)

I'm writing a new policy, the easiest one, over mode `User` to check if the logged user is the same user in the database so he can edit his profile, so...

I create the policy file:

```
> php artisan make:policy UserPolicy
```

I register the policy in `AuthServiceProvider.php`:

```
...
protected $policies = [
    // 'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    User::class => UserPolicy::class,
];
...
```

In `UserPolicy.php` I create the `edit` function:

```
public function edit(User $authUser, User $user) {
    return $authUser->id === $user->id;
}
```

In `UserController.php` I have `edit`:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    //
    $user     = User::findOrFail($id);

    $this->authorize($user);

    return view('user.edit', compact('user'));
}
```

See somwthing wrong? Me neither, because it worked... the first time. Then I wanted to change the policy, the `User` model has a `level` attribute, 1 for normal users, 5 for admins, 99 for superuser and so on. So I wanted that the admins or superuser would be able to change the user data, so I rewrote the `UserPolicy.php`'s `edit`function as:

```
public function edit(User $authUser, User $user) {
    return ($authUser->id === $user->id) || ($user->level > 1);
}
```

Of course I made a mistake here, I should've checked for `$authUser` and nor `$user`. When I checked in the browsser, function returned false, and server gave me a `403
This action is unauthorized.`, which is okay. Now the wierd thing. I correct the fuction:

```
public function edit(User $authUser, User $user) {
    return ($authUser->id === $user->id) || ($authUser->level > 1);
}
```

it returns 403...

```
public function edit(User $authUser, User $user) {
    return true;
}
```

It returns 403...

I delete the function from the file... It returns 403...

I delete the register from AuthServiceProvider... Ir returns 403...

No, I'm not using Gates, or some other thing, the Laravel app is almost virgin. I have had this problem in the past, that came out of the blue, and went the same way as it came. I have no idea where to look for, what to look for... I thought that would be some interaction that I didn't grasped, so I wanted to start with the policies from the beggining of this project.

EDIT::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
This is even more absurd... If I check using `can()` in tinker, this /#&)"# thing does what it is supposed to do:

```
> php artisan tinker
>>> $user = App\User::find(1)
>>> $user->can('edit', $user)
true
>>> $user2 = App\User::find(2)
>>> $user->can('edit', $user2)
false
```

So, problem is here????

```
$this->authorize($user);
```

EDIT 2 ::::::::::::: SOLVED ::::::::::::::::::::::

I swear this used to work as I posted above (at least it used to work in 5). I had to change

```
$this->authorize($user);
```

for

```
$this->authorize('edit', $user);
```

Solution came from this [article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/gates-and-policies-in-laravel--cms-29780)

Comment: Let's start with simple steps. Let's clear config `php artisan config:clear` and cache `php artisan cache:clear`. Do you see any update?

Comment: No, still giving 403. I even reverted to a previous branch on git, write all again from scratch and still giving 403

Comment: In this second time I'm just returning "true"

Comment: Try to add a `Log::info()` to your policy method. Just to make sure that at least it is being called.

Comment: Strange thing is, as I said, it worked as intended the first time, so I guess it was called, but next times, I even deleted the method, the registry and still gave me false (403), it was until I completely delete UserPolicy.php that the program broke and told me the file was missing

Comment: I added the `Log::info()` prior to the `return true`, and does nothing, it is not being reached.

Comment: I'm doing an edit, this is getting more absurd...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I swear this used to work as I posted above (at least it used to work in 5). I had to change

```
$this->authorize($user);
```

for

```
$this->authorize('edit', $user);
```

Solution came from this [article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/gates-and-policies-in-laravel--cms-29780)

Comment: No need to read post, the documentation is fine ;-)

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#via-controller-helpers